# Does @font-face not work on first gen iPod Touch?

Tags: css, mobile, font-face, ipod-touch

I'm trying to get the font family 'Lucia Calligraphy' to work on the first generation iPod Touch but its not working so far. And since I don't have any other mobile device I cant be 100% sure if its just this device or all mobile devices that don't support it.

```
 @font-face { font-family: 'Lucida Calligraphy';
              src: url('Lucida Calligraphy.eot?') format('eot'),
              url('Lucida Calligraphy.woff') format('woff'),
              url('Lucida Calligraphy.ttf') format('truetype');
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure before iOS 4.1 it only supported `.svg` fonts.

http://caniuse.com/#search=font-face

Comment: oh right thanks for letting me now. btw you wouldn't happen to now if my code is correct because when i get a chance im going to look at my site on a mobile device and want to make sure the code works and the font family is used.

Comment: In matters of inclusion snippet, you should use this one as it will tackle down some bug in IE: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/ (It's the snippets used in Font-Squirrel)